# Windows Azure Blob Storage . (dot) is ignored in an object name

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I use Windows Azure Blob Storage in my project to store data.
I upload files and folders. Folders are just 0 size object with a name ending with '/'

I found that if i try to name a folder with "zzz." then on azure i will get "zzz" (. is removed)
Also, z.z.z. is converted to zzz, but z.z.z is not converted. 
So , it looks like . in the end of object name makes all dots are removed.

Request is like

```
PUT myblob.blob.core.windows.net/myblobtop/zzz.?timeout=30
headers:
[Content-Encoding] => 
[Content-Language] => 
[Content-Length] => 0
[Content-MD5] => 
[Content-Type] => application/directory
[x-ms-version] => 2009-09-19
[Connection] => Keep-Alive
[x-ms-blob-type] => BlockBlob
```

and then there is object named myblobtop/zzz, no . in the end

Does anyone know what is this and how to solve?
Maybe some url encoding to encode . in the end?

I add folders with this API call https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have a . in the end of the blobname:

> Blob Names
>
> A blob name must conforming to the following naming rules: A blob name
>   can contain any combination of characters. A blob name must be at
>   least one character long and cannot be more than 1,024 characters
>   long.
>
> Blob names are case-sensitive.
>
> Reserved URL characters must be properly escaped. The number of path
>   segments comprising the blob name cannot exceed 254. A path segment is
>   the string between consecutive delimiter characters (e.g., the forward
>   slash '/') that corresponds to the name of a virtual directory.
>   System_CAPS_noteNote
>
> Avoid blob names that end with a dot (.), a forward slash (/), or a
>   sequence or combination of the two.
>
> The Blob service is based on a flat storage scheme, not a hierarchical
>   scheme. However, you may specify a character or string delimiter
>   within a blob name to create a virtual hierarchy. For example, the
>   following list shows valid and unique blob names. Notice that a string
>   can be valid as both a blob name and as a virtual directory name in
>   the same container:
>
> /a
>
> /a.txt
>
> /a/b
>
> /a/b.txt
>
> You can take advantage of the delimiter character when enumerating
>   blobs.

[Naming and Referencing containers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx)

Comment: yes. but it is not container. In my example 'myblobtop' is a container and zzz. is a folder. In my real tests, a container is also fine (just lower case letters)

Comment: Why add empty folders? a folder is just part of a blob name, so no need to create empty folders